# What is causing corrupted symbols in prompt? Suspect I'm missing an escape somewhere

Tags: bash, colors, prompt

I am getting some "corrupted" symbols diplaying both in my terminal prompt and also in the lowest portion of my vim instance. These seem to be some sort of color code reference, but I can't pinpoint where they might be coming from.

I found the `parse_git_branch()` and `strip_colors()` functions online. And the PS1 settings themselves were generated from either

https://scriptim.github.io/bash-prompt-generator/

http://ezprompt.net/

I say that just to clarify that I'm "not that good" at bash :p

Any tips on how to resolve? Thank you in advance!

**prompt**

[image: "Corrupted" symbols appearing in prompt]

**vim**

[image: And also in the lowest portion of the vim display]

```
force_color_prompt=yes

parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

strip_colors() {
    sed 's/\\[eE][[0-9]*;[0-9]*m//g' <<< $PS1
    # You can use it like this
    #     PS1="..."
    #     export PS1=$(strip_colors)
}

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    ...
    # green with 'default' text colors
    PS1="\n\[\e[32m\](\[\e[0m\]\u\[\e[32m\])(\[\e[0m\]jobs:\j\[\e[32m\])(\[\e[0m\]\w\[\e[32m\])\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\[\e[0m\]\$ "

else
    PS1="\n\[\e[32m\](\[\e[0m\]\u\[\e[32m\])(\[\e[0m\]jobs:\j\[\e[32m\])(\[\e[0m\]\w\[\e[32m\])\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\[\e[0m\]\$ "
    export PS1=$(strip_colors)
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Comment: I would be very doubtful of any function that claims to uncolor my PS1 prompt, as well as some other function that may insert anything in it, since PS1 contains all kinds of weird escape sequences and is thus likely to break if you blindly insert things there.

Comment: If I use the PS1 line and remove the `parse_git_branch` thing, the prompt displays correctly. If you can reproduce that, consider changing or altogether ditching those functions.

Comment: You're leading people on a wild goose chase.  [edit] your question to tell people the value of your `TERM` environment variable and the name of the terminal emulator that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Quasimodo and @JdeBP!

I got rid of the `strip_colors()` function and replaced the `parse_git_branch()` function with the following. Since then I haven't had any more issues.

```
# get current branch in git repo, from ezprompt.net
function parse_git_branch() {
    BRANCH=`git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'`
    if [ ! "${BRANCH}" == "" ]
    then
        STAT=`parse_git_dirty`
        echo "[${BRANCH}${STAT}]"
    else
        echo ""
    fi
}

# get current status of git repo
function parse_git_dirty {
    status=`git status 2>&1 | tee`
    dirty=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "modified:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
    untracked=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "Untracked files" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
    ahead=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "Your branch is ahead of" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
    newfile=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "new file:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
    renamed=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "renamed:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
    deleted=`echo -n "${status}" 2> /dev/null | grep "deleted:" &> /dev/null; echo "$?"`
    bits=''
    if [ "${renamed}" == "0" ]; then
        bits=">${bits}"
    fi
    if [ "${ahead}" == "0" ]; then
        bits="*${bits}"
    fi
    if [ "${newfile}" == "0" ]; then
        bits="+${bits}"
    fi
    if [ "${untracked}" == "0" ]; then
        bits="?${bits}"
    fi
    if [ "${deleted}" == "0" ]; then
        bits="x${bits}"
    fi
    if [ "${dirty}" == "0" ]; then
        bits="!${bits}"
    fi
    if [ ! "${bits}" == "" ]; then
        echo " ${bits}"
    else
        echo ""
    fi
}

# Use like:
# export PS1="\`parse_git_branch\` "
```